# SQL Query with multiple joins only returning first result on final join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

So I have a prepared SQL query (below) that joins 4 tables together based on the user's ID. The final relationship however is a one to many (a user can have more than one skill) so I need all rows returned where the skill ID equals the user ID. At the moment only the first row that matches the user ID in the `freelancer_skill` table returns. How do I get all rows to return?

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.bio, u.portfolio, u.location, u.time_joined, u.image_location, 
    f.freelancer_id, f.jobtitle, f.priceperhour, 
    ut.*,
    ft.testimonial, ft.testimonial_source,
    fs.skill, fs.skill_rating
FROM ((((users AS u
    LEFT JOIN freelancers AS f
ON u.user_id = f.freelancer_id)
    LEFT JOIN user_types AS ut
ON u.user_id = ut.user_type_id)
    LEFT JOIN freelancer_testimonials AS ft
ON u.user_id = ft.testimonial_id)
    LEFT JOIN freelancer_skills AS fs
ON u.user_id = fs.skill_id)
WHERE 
    u.confirmed = :confirmed
AND u.user_id = :userID
AND ut.user_type = :userType
AND u.granted_access = :grantedAccess
```

**EDIT**

Updated code with user type `WHERE` clause moved into join:

```
SELECT 
    u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.bio, u.portfolio, u.location, u.time_joined, u.image_location, 
    f.jobtitle, f.priceperhour, 
    ut.user_type,
    ft.testimonial, ft.testimonial_source,
    fs.skill, fs.skill_rating
FROM ((((" . DB_NAME . ".users AS u
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_NAME . ".freelancers AS f
ON u.user_id = f.freelancer_id)
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_NAME . ".user_types AS ut
ON u.user_id = ut.user_type_id AND ut.user_type = :userType)
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_NAME . ".freelancer_testimonials AS ft
ON u.user_id = ft.testimonial_id)
    RIGHT JOIN " . DB_NAME . ".freelancer_skills AS fs
ON u.user_id = fs.skill_id)
WHERE 
    u.confirmed = :confirmed
AND u.user_id = :userID
AND u.granted_access = :grantedAccess
```

To fetch the results I am using fetch (below). I've tried using fetchALL which does return each skill a user holds but also returns duplicates of their data for each skill.

```
$results->execute();
$user = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $user;
```

Here is an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7bb3/4

Comment: Are you sure all the joins should be defined on `u.user_id` column? Don't you have separate columns in users table that match different joins?

Comment: can you post some sample data for us to work with?

Comment: Run your query without the `WHERE` clause. Most probably the condition in where is knocking off the results.

Comment: I can't run the query without the `WHERE` clause as the data always needs to be restricted to the :userID parameter. If I change the `WHERE` clause to just `WHERE u.user_id = :userID`, I get exactly the same data (ie. first row only)

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Here is an SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7bb3/4  This is duplicating data for each skill a user has (in this case 3) - My desired result set would be one row with 3 skills?

Answer (score 0):

You have a filter in the wrong place.  You are declaring a left join to user_types but are filtering on that table in the where clause.  That makes it an implicit inner join.  Move

```
and ut.user_type = :userType
```

to follow this:

```
LEFT JOIN user_types AS ut ON u.user_id = ut.user_type_id
```

That might be the cause of your problem, but even if it's not, you will still get unexpected results with that filter in the where clause.

Comment: Hey, I updated the query to `LEFT JOIN user_types AS u ON u.user_id = ut.user_type_id AND ut.user_type = :userType` but it returns exactly the same data as it did before. Could it be the other where clauses causing the issue? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

change the order of the joins. Swap the Users table and freelancer_skills table.
-This apparently does not work.

Maybe try something like this instead. Not ideal if you want to list a hundred skills for one person.

```
SELECT  
u.firstname, 
u.lastname, 
u.email, u.bio, u.portfolio, u.location, u.time_joined, u.image_location,
f.jobtitle, f.priceperhour,
ut.user_type,
ft.testimonial, ft.testimonial_source,
count(case when fs.skill = 'HTML5' then 1 end) as HTML5, 
count(case when fs.skill = 'CSS3' then 1 end) as CSS3, 
count(case when fs.skill = 'PHP' then 1 end) as PHP, 
fs.skill_rating
FROM 
(
  (
    (
      (
       users AS u
  LEFT JOIN freelancers AS f ON 
  u.user_id = f.freelancer_id
  )
  LEFT JOIN user_types AS ut ON 
  u.user_id = ut.user_type_id AND 
  ut.user_type = 'developer'
)
LEFT JOIN freelancer_testimonials AS ft ON 
u.user_id = ft.testimonial_id
)
RIGHT JOIN freelancer_skills AS fs ON 
u.user_id = fs.skill_id
 )
  WHERE
  u.confirmed = '1'
  AND u.user_id = '3'
  AND u.granted_access = '1'
  group by 
  u.firstname, 
  u.lastname, 
  u.email, u.bio, u.portfolio, 
  u.location, 
  u.time_joined, u.image_location,
  f.jobtitle, f.priceperhour,
  ut.user_type,
  fs.skill_rating
```

Comment: Minus 1.  The order of the joins is irrelevant.